# Url encoding issue with url connection

Tags: java, android, url, encoding, utf-8

Please help me to encode the url:

```
http://dsxsd.com/def/fss/default/files/10 رسم الصباح - 1.mp3
```

I need to download this file in android app.
when i am trying to make url connection it gives me 404. but on browser the url is working. 
when i pasted browser encoded url its working fine.

But i can't hardcore the things as i have my urls like this coming from server.

I tried to encode using Urlencoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");
but server call gives me wrong url I am getting "java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: http%3A%2F%........

have this url not separate path params and query params to encode separately.

please help me in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have the URL, use this method

```
private String encodeUrl(String link) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Uri uri = (Uri.parse(link));
    String result = null;
    if (Objects.equals(uri.getScheme(), "content")) {
        try (Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null)) {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
            }
        }
    }
    if (result == null) {
        result = uri.getPath();
        int cut = Objects.requireNonNull(result).lastIndexOf('/');
        if (cut != -1) {
            result = result.substring(cut + 1);
        }
    }
    return link.replace(result
            ,URLEncoder.encode(result, "UTF-8")
                    .replace("+", "%20"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're encoding the entire URL, you only need to encode the filename, e.g.

```
String filename = Uri.encode("10 رسم الصباح - 1.mp3");
String url = "http://dsxsd.com/def/fss/default/files/" + filename;
```

Comment: I am getting this url from server. I am not configuring it locally .

BTW i tried to sub string it and encoding it it is returing  http://dsxsd.com/def/fss/default/files/10+%D8%B1%D8%B3%D9%85+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%AD+-+1.mp3

which is not a right url.

Comment: In that case, you could split the URL and just encode the last part of that path.

Comment: that is not helping me out. spaces creates problem .

Comment: @Philio no it won't... `"+"` is not a valid regex... You probably mean `.replace()`, and even then the set of characters `URLEncoder` encodes is not the same set as required by a URI path segment; see the README of the project I linked to for more details...

Comment: True, it would need to be escaped. However, Uri.encode is a better solution anyway as it correctly encodes spaces. Solution updated.

Answer (score 1):

Use [URI templates](https://github.com/fge/uri-template): `URLEncoder.encode()` does not work.

Usage of the library above:

```
final URITemplate template = new URITemplate("http://dsxsd.com/def/" +
    "fss/default/files/{filename}");

final VariableMap vars = VariableMap.newBuilder()
    .addScalarValue("filename", "10 رسم الصباح - 1.mp3")
    .freeze();

System.out.println(template.toString(vars));
```

Output:

```
http://dsxsd.com/def/fss/default/files/10%20%D8%B1%D8%B3%D9%85%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%AD%20-%201.mp3
```

Comment: For this particular example, your library doesn't achieve anything that you cannot achieve with URLEncoder.

Comment: agree but, and library looks promising . 

can't i get a simple project other than Gradle build.
its hard for person who don't use Gradle to configure it.

Comment: @Rajivyadav why clone the project? Just use the gradle/maven artifact

Comment: sorry i am getting . Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: ASL-2.0.txt
Origin 1: /home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.fge/jackson-coreutils/1.5/5108553833b399fed6a1f7f979b89a07b786d3c2/jackson-coreutils-1.5.jar
Origin 2: /home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.fge/btf/1.1/597aaacc063dcf8b77c17729706b895c562b162e/btf-1.1.jar

Comment: @Rajivyadav that looks like a bug... Could you open a bug in github? In particular, describe your build environment (what is APK for instance?)

Comment: its android package file.

Comment: do you know any other light weight libray which i can add for this small work.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't, sorry. But please open a bug with the full stack trace etc. Don't you have an option to ignore duplicate files?